# Multiple UITableViewCell types programmatically

Tags: ios, uitableview

I am writing an app in Swift 4 programmatically.

I'd like to create a settings page that would contain a UITableView, however the rows in this will contain different types of content.

For example, I'd like a row that has a slider, a row that has a uiswitch, a row that contains a text input and so on.

I imagine the approach for this, is to create a custom cell class for each type of cell I would like to use?

However, currently I create my cells as such :

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellID, for: indexPath) as! CustomCell
    cell.rowContent.text = items[indexPath.row]
    cell.tableViewController = self
    return cell
}
```

How can I downcast my cell based on it's content?

Comment: For a settings table view use **static** cells and `IBOutlet`s and omit the data source.

Comment: you should know (from your _model_) the cell's type for each row, and based on that information you could create e.g. `switch ... case ...` branches to downcast the dequeued cell for its correct type, before you populate it with your _model_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you're trying to do a form, if so I'd suggest [Eureka](https://github.com/xmartlabs/Eureka)

otherwise you'd register the cell, then dequeue your cell of choice depending on index or any other factor you'd like :

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    switch indexPath.section{
    case 1:
         let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellID, for: indexPath) as! CustomCell
    cell.rowContent.text = items[indexPath.row]
    cell.tableViewController = self
    return cell 
    case 2:
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: secondCustomcellID, for: indexPath) as! AnotherCustomCell
    cell.rowContent.text = items[indexPath.row]
    cell.tableViewController = self
    return cell
    }

}
```